# Famo Crosswalk: How can I run Famo.us app using Crosswalk platform?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, famo.us, crosswalk-runtime

I have tried various ways given in documentation to run famo.us app which is running using android application. As the famo.us animations are not running smooth, I want to run it using Crosswalk application to run smoothly as crosswalk provides chromium browser.

Can anyone tell the step wise description of which plugins to install in eclipse and the execution process of creating .apk file?

Comment: there is a full step by step guide on crosswalk-project.org, can you be more specific? what have you tried? what step didnt work?

Comment: Hi @amir bar I want to  wrap my Famo.us app code with crosswalk without using python. Please tell me the solution for that using eclipse only, as in  crosswalk-project.org the description is quite confusing. Is it possible?

Comment: crosswalk as nothing to do with your js code.. its just wraping your code in chrome browser.. did you follow the step by step guide? on what step did you have problem?

Comment: Which eclipse version is required to run the crosswalk application?

Comment: I have used eclipse plugin with url https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk-developer-tools-eclipse-plugin and followed the steps given here. But when I am trying to export crosswalk project then error comes as "The crosswalk app export failed"

Comment: @amir bar. Even I have gone through the code in url https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/embedding_crosswalk.html and followed the instructions mentioned but when we run android application to android device  the message comes as"The applicationName stoped unfortunately" I am not getting what I am missing or doing anything wrong?

Comment: the cordova crosswalk is good for you? https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova.html if you have problems even with that you can build with cordova crosswalk using intel xdk

Comment: Thank you so much! Using intel XDK its so easy :)